# Java application won't start after exporting

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation

Noob here.

Using Eclipse to try and program a cost calculator.

Source code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Costtransport {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double ctotal;
        double ctransp;
        double cpers;
        double persvar1;
        double persvar2;


        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Care este costul total al comenzii, excluzand transportul");
        ctotal = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Care este costul transportului?");
        ctransp = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Care este valoarea produselor cumparate de individul pentru care se calculeaza taxa de transport?");
        cpers = keyboard.nextInt();
        persvar1 = cpers / ctotal;
        persvar2 = ctransp * persvar1;
        System.out.print("Persoana respectiva trebuie sa plateasca ");
        System.out.print(persvar2);
        System.out.println( " lei.");

        keyboard.close();
        }


    }
```

If I try to run it in Eclipse, it runs fine. However, if I try to export it, it won't start.

Tried exporting it as "runnable JAR file" and as "JAR file". I've been reading about some manifest file, but the latter option should generate it apparently.

Any help please?

Thank you.

Comment: can you share error logs.

Comment: LE: I've also tried the jarfix, that resets the file association, still not working.

Comment: Cody, the code compiles without any errors. Where can I find that log?

Comment: Did you export it as "running jar file"?

Comment: What do you mean by `it won't start`? If it works in Eclipse, it is highly to be a problem in your code

Comment: run it from cmd .do you see any errors? `java -jar <jar-file-name>.jar`

Comment: I start the .jar file, the command prompt shows up for a very brief instant, disappears. Nothing happens.

Comment: java -jar <jar-file-name>.jar > tmp/log.txt This will send logs to a file.

Comment: It works from command prompt

Comment: What is causing this and how can I fix it? The log only shows "Care este costul total al comenzii, excluzand transportul
Care este costul transportului?
Care este valoarea produselor cumparate de individul pentru care se calculeaza taxa de transport?
Persoana respectiva trebuie sa plateasca 123.0 lei.
"

Comment: Which basically is the program running with no flaws, no error code

Comment: @GabrielNBJJ create a bat file.it will open jar with cmd

Comment: That doesn't really solve the problem as I need to send it to other people and I want it to work for them as well.

Comment: @GabrielNBJJ console applications works that way.your friend can also run bat file.if you want to convert you can convert it to console exe using softwares like exe4j.then it will work as you expect

Comment: Yep, I fixed this with a .jar to .exe converter. Thank you guys <3

Answer (score 2):

If you create an executable `jar`, you're gonna wanna use it mainly for GUI applications (`Swing, FX..`).

Remember that the jar will not start the console on its own !

You can either create your own, or run the jar from terminal, so that the output can be displayed.

```
java -jar <yourfile>
```

If you want the console at all costs, make one with a black `JPanel` and a `JTextArea`.